# Deployment Problems Experience (Network - no Network named "...." found)

Tags: deployment, experience-bundle

I am currently trying the deployment of the Experience Cloud. Unfortunately, I am encountering the problem with the "Network" and that it cannot find them. I have attached a screenshot from Bitbucket.

However, these files still exist in the branch. Thanks for any feedback and help.

Best regards,

Eric

[image]

Entry 2:

The missing metadata according to the error message is stored in the branch. I have attached a picture for this purpose. Retrieving the package.xml for "CustomeSite" and "ExperienceBundle" does not lead to any further results.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because you have not added **Network** metadata to the build. Make sure to add [Network](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_network.htm) metadata along with CustomSite and the ExperienceBundle.

Check the docs [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_migrate_expbundle.htm).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've already had Network, Experience Bundle and CustomSites into my commit. The solution was to rename the Network metadata file, adding "*-meta.xml*" after the extension "*.network*". See the example below:

**Before change:**
*My Community.network*

**After change:**
*My Community.network-meta.xml*

When you do this, git will interpret the ***My Community.network-meta.xml*** as a **new file to be added** and ***My Community.network*** as a **file to be deleted**. After that, the deploy/validation was successful.