# Failure to deploy Experience Cloud Site with Metadata API - no network named XXX found

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, experience-cloud, experience-bundle

I'm following the Salesforce documentation [Deploy Your Experience Cloud Site with the Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm). I am using a simple site created from the Customer Account Portal Template as a test case before applying this approach to the company's real site.

I get the error (see images) "no Network named Partners_Portal_Test found " despite the fact that this network is in my manifest and the file Partners_Portal_Test.network-meta.xml is available.

I am also getting the error "no SiteDotCom named Partners_Portal_Test21 found" despite the fact that I am using ExperienceBundle.

I have reviewed [this similar Stack Exchange post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/353206/deployment-problems-experience-network-no-network-named-found), but seem to be having a different issue.

I'm doing the deployment from VSCode using SFDX: Deploy Source to Org. I'm trying to deploy from a dev sandbox to our staging sandbox.

Has anyone else faced this issue and solved it? Actually, has anyone successfully used this approach for deploying an Experience Cloud Site from a sandbox to another sandbox?

[image: error messages in vscode]

[image: package.xml]

Comment: Simple question, Have you enabled experience bundle in your settings in the org you are replying to?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava yes, I have enabled experience bundle in both orgs.